# C# integer variable in foreach loop

Tags: c#, variables, foreach, integer

In C# I have a foreach loop where I want to ++ a integer.

The code is like this:

```
private void btnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   int Counter = 0;
   foreach (SettingsProperty currrentProperty in Properties.Settings.Default.Properties)
   {
      Counter++;
   }
   lblText.Text = Counter.ToString();
}
```

Simple, but of course because I have to assing the integer the variable sticks to 0, otherwise the compiler errors. So the `lblText.Text` prints 0 to me.

I just can't get it working properly..
Sure this is an easy one, but I couldn't find a awnser.

Comment: Are you sure `Properties.Settings.Default.Properties` isn't empty?

Comment: What ***exactly*** happens when you say "compiler errors"? what is the exact text? Basically, that should be fine.

Comment: @MarcGravell I believe he's talking about the definite assignment error that the compiler would raise if the declaration lacked an assignment (`int Counter; ...`)

Comment: @phoog well, the code *as shown* would not suffer from "definite assignment", hence why I think we should get more information first.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a Properties.Settings.Default.Properties.Count() that does this already for you?

Comment: @user1614456 this would be a great time to jump in with some additional information to clarify the question...

Comment: The code as posted ought to work and can be shortened with `Default.Properties.Count`.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the comments! Count did seem to do the job just fine. But the Properties did contain 5 settings. So that couldn't be it. :P Still kinda wierd that the code didn't work properly...

Comment: `int Counter = Properties.Settings.Default.Properties.Count;`

Comment: Hmm in fact, cleaned up the code, it seems to work out just fine. Mine was a bit different, but made a small silly mistake in it. Thanks again guys!

Answer (score 1):

I think that `Properties.Settings.Default.Properties` is empty . So to get sure that it is empty try:

```
private void btnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{  
   if(Properties.Settings.Default.Properties.Count != 0)
   {
      int Counter = 0;
      foreach (SettingsProperty currrentProperty in Properties.Settings.Default.Properties)
      {
         Counter++;
         //Some stuff here else just use .Count without use a foreach
      }
      lblText.Text = Counter.ToString();
   } 
   else
      throw new Exception("Properties.Settings.Default.Properties is empty");
}
```

Else try to set some *breakpoints* before compile the code.